# Couchbase Metadata overhead warning

Tags: couchbase, nosql

I have a Couchbase (v 2.0.1) cluster with the following specifications:

- 5 Nodes
- 1 Bucket
- 16 GB Ram per node (80GB Total)
- 200GB Disk per node (1Tb Total)

Currently I have 201.000.000 documents in this bucket and only 200GB of disk in use.

I'm getting the following warning every minute for every node:

```
Metadata overhead warning. Over 51% of RAM allocated to bucket "my-bucket" on node "my-node" is taken up by keys and metadata.
```

The Couchbase documentation states the following:

> Indicates that a bucket is now using more than 50% of the allocated
>   RAM for storing metadata and keys, reducing the amount of RAM
>   available for data values.

I understand that this could be a helpful indicator that I may need to add nodes to my cluster but I think this should not be necessary given the amount of resources available to the bucket.

General Bucket Analytics:
[image: General Bucket Analytics]

How could I know what is generating so much metadata?

Is there any way to configure the tolerance percentage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every document has metadata and a key stored in memory.  The metadata is 56 bytes.  Add that to your average key size and multiply the result times your document count to arrive at the total bytes for metadata and key in memory.  So the RAM required is affected by the doc count, your key size, and the number of copies (replica count + 1).  You can find details at http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#memory-quota.  The specific formula there is:

```
(documents_num) * (metadata_per_document + ID_size) * (no_of_copies)
```

You can get details about the user and metadata being used by your cluster from the console (or via REST or command line interface).  Look at the 'VBUCKET RESOURCES' section.  The specific values of interest are 'user data in RAM' and 'metadata in RAM'.  From your screenshot, you are definitely running up against your memory capacity.  You are over the low water mark, so the system will eject inactive replica documents from memory.  If you cross the high water mark, the system will then start ejecting active documents from memory until it reaches the low water mark.  any requests for ejected documents will then require a background disk fetch.  From your screenshot, you have less than 5% of your active documents in memory already.

It is possible to change the warning metadata warning threshold in the 2.5.1 release.  There is a script you can use located at https://gist.github.com/fprimex/11368614.  Or you can simply leverage the curl command from the script and plug in the right values for your cluster.  As far as I know, this will not work prior to 2.5.1.

Please keep in mind that while these alerts (max overhead and max disk usage) are now tunable, they are there for a reason. Hitting either of these alerts (especially in production) at the default values is a major cause for concern and should be dealt with as soon as possible by increasing RAM and/or disk on every node, or adding nodes. The values are tunable for special cases. Even in development/testing scenarios, your nodes' performance may be significantly impaired if you are hitting these alerts. For example, don't draw conclusions about benchmark results if your nodes' RAM is over 50% consumed by metadata.

Comment: As you mentioned upgrading to 2.5.1. It is worth pointing out that in later versions the ejection policy change to where data now only gets eject once the high watermark has been hit.

Comment: Hi, I add the VBucket resources. Applying the formula: (207000000 items × (56+27) bytes ×2 copies) = 34362000000 bytes ~ 32GB. According to this it should not reach 50% of RAM. There are any way to not save the metadata in memory? Thx

Comment: I see from the new VBUCKET RESOURCES screenshot that the metadata RAM usage is showing as 36.8GB.  That is somewhat close to your ~32GB calculation.  Perhaps the key size is off slightly in the calculation.  A small difference is magnified when operating across large document counts of course.

As for not saving metadata, there is not a way to achieve that in 2.5.1 and earlier versions.  In the next release, Couchbase plans to deliver a tunable memory feature that allows you to optionally eject metadata and keys for documents ejected from memory.  This will help scenarios with low resident %.